# Problema la función table: "all arguments must have the same length"

Tags: r, funciones

estoy creando una función en R para obtener las frecuencias y frecuencias relativas, contando también los NA.

```
freq.porc<- function(data, useNA="always") {
 x<- table(data, useNA)
 y<- prop.table(x)
 z<- cbind(x,y)
 colnames(z)<- c("freq", "%")
 print(z)
}
```

Sin embargo, cuando hago la prueba me aparece el siguiente error:

> Error in table(data, useNA) : all arguments must have the same length

¿Alguien sabe qué sucede?

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido Alexis a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Que datos le pasas a la función por el parámetro `data`?¿podrías mostrarnos un ejemplo?

Comment: Creo que tienes un error muy básico, casi diría tipográfico,  con `x <- table(data, useNA)`, debiera ser `x <- table(data, useNA=useNA)`, pruebalo, si es eso, elaboro una respuesta mejor

Comment: Gracias @Patricio por tu respuesta. Efectivamente el error era tipográfico, hice lo que me comentaste y resolví mi problema. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es la llamada a la función `table()`, veamos la documentación de la misma mediante `?table`, particularmente la definición de los parámetros:

```
Arguments
... 
one or more objects which can be interpreted as factors (including character strings), or a list (or data frame) whose components can be so interpreted. (For as.table, arguments passed to specific methods; for as.data.frame, unused.)

exclude 
levels to remove for all factors in .... If it does not contain NA and useNA is not specified, it implies useNA = "ifany". See ‘Details’ for its interpretation for non-factor arguments.

useNA   
whether to include NA values in the table. See ‘Details’. Can be abbreviated.


...etc.
```

Como puedes observar el primer argumento posicionalmente es `...` que indica justamente un número variable de argumentos, esto condiciona el resto de la llamada y te obliga a usar los nombres de parámetros para indicar el resto de los mismos. De ahí el error, cuando haces:

```
x <- table(data, useNA)
```

Lo que ocurre es que tanto `data`, como `useNA` se consideran como parte del parámetro variable `...`, de ahí el error en las dimensiones, `useNA` obviamente no tiene las mismas dimensiones que `data`. La solución para indicar cualquiera  de los parámetros adicionales es indicarlo de la forma `párametro = valor` . es decir:

```
x <- table(data, useNA = useNA)
```